# Как сделать четкое изображение текста на картинке?

Tags: html, css

Не могу додуматься, как сделать, чтобы при "image:hover" картинка расплывалась, появлялся текст, но не размытый.

http://jsfiddle.net/t1wf8gmq/

Comment: Картинка расплывалась - это как?

Answer (score 1):

[Проверяем](http://jsfiddle.net/t1wf8gmq/2/)

```
.image:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
.image:hover a {
    opacity:1;
}
```